# Cross schema joins in Tableau

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

I came a cross a problem on Tableau version 9.1.0 but I'm new to this system and I'm not sure I'm doing this right.

Here's the relevant part of the screenshot:

[image]

In Oracle (and DB2?) a database is an instance, ("a whole server"). So it's natural that Tableau won't join queries in between Oracle databases. But in MySQL a database is just what we call a schema on other RDBMS.

Since Tableau uses JDBC, they've apparently leveled all database drivers to mean that a database is a conection ("data source")?

Which has this implication: in MySQL or PGSql I cannot use qualified table names to join them. If you have organized your data into multiple schemas, Tableau cannot join them.

tl;dr; Tableau can only query one schema at a time under MySQL? Is this correct or am I doing something terribly wrong here? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Just a point of clarification. For MySql, Tableau uses ODBC, not JDBC. http://www.tableau.com/support/drivers

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question hoping this helps fellow S.O. members who might come across this issue.

To accomplish what I was trying to do here:

- Drag any random table to the top area.
- Go to the Data menu and select "Convert to Custom SQL"
- A notepad-like screen pops up and lets you edit any arbitrary SQL.

So far I've tested some simple multi schema joins, including the specific one I needed, and everything works fine.

I hope this will be made possible in the future using their popular drag and drop interface.

[Credit to rainman_104 and the kind folks over at Reddit /r/Tableau](https://www.reddit.com/r/tableau/comments/3s4eyo/i_need_to_join_two_tables_for_two_different/)